# ssh login on raspberryPI accepted on hostname but not on local ip

Tags: authentication, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a raspPi working as a local server. Recently I had to renew the https self-signed certificate (suddenly after 5 years...)

Now seemingly unrelated I can login when doing ssh pi@myhostname

```
(base) me@<other>:~$ ssh pi@<hostname>
pi@<hostname>'s password: 

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
You have new mail.
Last login: Tue Nov 26 07:44:43 2019 from <other>.home
pi@<hostname>:~ $
```

but trying to login with pi@192.168.1.xxx does not accept my password (believe me I have tried many times)

```
(base) me@<other>:~$ ssh pi@192.168.1.xxx
pi@192.168.1.xxx's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.1.xxx's password:
```

I have never come across such thing. Note that I had to re-accept the pi as known host with both methods (because of certificate renewal?) and that I have changed computer in the meantime. I have tried google but could not find anything giving me a hint where to search for.

here the output of ssh -v pi@192.168.1.xxx

```
(base) me@<other>:~$ ssh -v pi@192.168.1.xxx
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.xxx [192.168.1.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.xxx:22 as 'pi'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression:     none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:8ofojxAYFocyI8FVe4mSzUXk/+qb7vARTRir30zJ6xo
debug1: Host '192.168.1.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:34
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-    dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:0xagiyXErFhFPGMqVlyzbNWP+cXgJ2viL1KhAww380s /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:a0FFNOSt5iM6wbF3xgEMwolqayoI4E6TfmLtq14zGG0 me@<yet another>
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@192.168.1.xxx's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.1.xxx's password:
```

Comment: Could you post the content of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` here, please?

Comment: Or you can login to the server using `pi@<hostname>` and tail the `/var/log/auth.log` and try to ssh from another window/tab using `pi@192.168.1.xxx` and post the errors server throw as well.